# What css or html is causing "Currently, testing ..." not to be displayed in Safari, but in other browsers?

Tags: html, css, safari

On this url http://wpbeta.nfshost.com/simplysimple/index.html, there is text "Currently, testing... " in the center of the page, but it does not display in Safari.  It displays in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: Not really sure, but maybe something to do with the `color:white` in the `::selection { }` or the crazy font in the `body` tag? `font-family: "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- The text is getting overlapped by the fixed header with the solid white background.
- This is happening because of differences in how the browsers are interpreting `</br>&nbsp;` in your paragraphs.
- Technically, these should be `<br />&nbsp;`, but realistically you should be creating that whitespace using CSS styles, not line breaks.

Try this HTML:

```
<header id="fixednav">...</header>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Currently testing</h1>
    <p>&quot;I believe that one day&hellip;&quot;</p>
    <p>-Cool Dude <a href="http://someurl.com" desc="giant mango site">someurl.com</a></p>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#fixednav {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -275px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#main {
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}
```